# Cleaning messy observations while keeping information

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

I'm practising my importing and cleaning skills and have reached a bit of a quagmire. I've been importing from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_firearm-related_death_rate). The importing works and I have been able to drop na's. However, the issue is that certain observations are written in such a way (for example `13.7 (2016)`). Because of how they're written they're read in as strings and even if they weren't they would contain false information.

I want to get rid of the year observations which are in the parentheses but preserve the data observation itself.

At present here is my code:

```
#Declare Missing Variables
missing_values = ['?', np.nan]
#Read Data
dfs = pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_firearm-related_death_rate', na_values=missing_values)
#Set Dataset and Drop Variables
df = dfs[3]
df_drops = df[['Year', 'Undetermined', 'Sources and notes']]
df.drop(df_drops, inplace = True, axis=1)

print(df)
# pd.to_numeric(df['Guns per 100 inhabitants'])
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Bit of a workaround, but you could clean it up by splitting the string by a space and then taking the first entry.

```py
df['Guns per 100 inhabitants (clean)'] = np.array([float(s.split(' ')[0]) for s in df['Guns per 100 inhabitants'])
```

I tried it out with your example and there are still some errors (for example, one entry is formatted '6.2-19.4', and some entries are already floats not strings so `s.split(' ')` throws an error) but I think this solves the year in parentheses issue.

Comment: Yeah this is a pretty good go. I might just clean it in excel instead. Thanks for your help regardless.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Chris's solution but using regex

```py
import re
df['Guns per 100 inhabitants'].map(lambda x: float(re.findall("(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)", x)[0]) if isinstance(x, str) else x)
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a fantastic example. I was wondering about using `re` for the issue.